# how to stop dotnet ef migrations adding from creating unnecessary additional fields

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration

This is a barebones application with only one class:  AppUser having only (Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone1, Phone2, KnownAs, EmailAddress, Question, Answer, and IsTrialMode.

There are no other tables!

```
DataContext is only:

    public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

When I do a dotnet ef migrations add command, the migrations file contains:

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Users",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Phone1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Phone2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                KnownAs = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                EmailAddress = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Question = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Answer = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                IsTrialMode = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
            });
```

This is clearly NOT what I was expecting.
What is causing this; how to make it stop?

Thanks in advance.
"Chuck"

Comment: Have a look at your entity class definitions to check that you don't have a base User class. Your code mentions an AppUser entity, but the Migration is using a Users table. It doesn't look like the ASP.Net authenticaiton as that is normally named AspNetUser, but it looks like something similar is at play.

Comment: Can you show us  AppUser class ?

Comment: From your migration file, the additional property seems to be the IdentityUser default property, be sure your AppUser does not extend IdentityUser or IdentityUser<T> class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your migration file, the additional properties seem to be the `IdentityUser` class default properties.

[image]

Be sure your AppUser does not extend `IdentityUser` or `IdentityUser<T>` class:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    public string KnownAs { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrialMode { get; set; }
}
```